# SCSS global styles not working in Next JS App

Tags: import, sass, next.js

I'm creating a NextJS App using SASS but the global styles are not getting applied.

I read the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support) and installed `sass`. Problem is: `globals.scss` is not getting imported into app.

_*app.js*

```js
import "./styles/globals.scss";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

*Note: I know sass itself is not the problem because `Home.module.scss` is getting imported successfully in `Home` component inside `index.js`.*

Answer (score -1):

The problem was with the folder structure!

I'm more familiar with React so I wanted to add a [`src` directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/src-directory). My project structure was like this:

```
src
├── pages
│   └── index.js
│
├── styles
│   ├── globals.scss
│   └── Home.module.scss
│
├── _app.js ❌
└── _document.js
```

My mistake was that I ended up taking out `_app.js` from the `pages` directory. Putting it back solved the problem!